# Computer Organizaton and Architecture

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

[image]

why he doesn't add mux before regs that choose write register?

why he doesn't add mux before regs that choose write register ?
I add the time for regdst mux why he doesn't add mux before regs that choose write register ?